# How do I turn a Pygame Folder into an application (eg .exe)?

Tags: python, file, pygame, directory, exe

I'm new to this so sorry it if doesn't make much sense.

I'v created a simple 2d game with Python 3.4 and Pygame and I want to create an exe file that includes python 3.4, the pygame module, the game files and launches the python game file when opened.

Thanks.

Comment: py2exe doesn't work with Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.x, you can use cx_Freeze.

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller works like a charm.

1. Install PyInstaller found [here](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), move it into your Python directory.
2. Move your .py file into your Python folder(normally C:\Python34)
3. Start Menu>Run>cmd
4. Enter this command: cd C:\Python[press tab here], then enter
5. Then this command: cd PyInstaller[press tab here], then enter
6. move your .py file into the PyInstaller directory
7. (Still in cmd) put in this command: pyinstaller.py --onefile --noconsole "your.py file".py
8. Hit enter, navigate to the directory in the PyInstaller directory named after your file, go to "dist", and there will be your file.

EDIT: Not sure if pyinstaller accepts 3.4, sorry.